Keep Getting BAD Request on JSON Body
Here's my code
 var url = "<SOMEURL>";
 var apiKey = "<SOMEKEY>";

 var client = new HttpClient();
 var uri = new Uri(url);

/** I believed something wrong here, if I changed the value into hard-code value it works **/
 var json = $@"{{
                 ""Uin"": ""{projectRecordsJson.Uin}"",
                 ""ProjectId"": ""{projectRecordsJson.ProjectId}"",
                 ""DeleteFlag"": ""{projectRecordsJson.DeleteFlag}"",
                 ""Type"": ""{projectRecordsJson.Type}"",
                 ""StopDate"": ""{projectRecordsJson.StopDate}"",
                 ""TerminationFlag"": ""{projectRecordsJson.TerminationFlag}"",
                 ""A05Flag"": ""{projectRecordsJson.A05Flag}""
             }}";
 
 var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

 // Add API key as a request header
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-API-Key", apiKey);

 var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);

 if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
 {
     var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
     Console.WriteLine("Response:");
     Console.WriteLine(responseContent);
 }
 else
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Error:");
     Console.WriteLine($"{response.StatusCode} - {response.ReasonPhrase}");
 }

I did tried to hard code the value and it works, now I need 'value' part to be coming
from the variable and that's where I'm getting a bad request error

Can you share the hardcoded string value that works?

Please don't manually create JSON like this. Doing so is prone to error. You should really use JsonContent.Create passing projectRecordsJson.

Where does projectRecordsJson come from? What is the resulting value of json? How does it compare to the hard-coded string that works?

This code isn't just error prone, it creates temporary strings, thus using more memory than System.Text.Json would. It's not enough to check ReasonPhrase either. The server may return a response that explains what's wrong, especially when validation fails. There's a standard way to return detailed request problems that's supported by ASP.NET Core out of the box

Here's the hard-coded value that works:  var json = @"{
""Uin"": ""1234567890"",
""ProjectId"": ""4348"",
""DeleteFlag"": """",
""Type"": ""H"",
""StopDate"": ""2024-03-28T17:21:06.458Z"",
""TerminationFlag"": ""N"",
""A05Flag"": """"
}";

Please include that in the question rather than down here where it's difficult to find and read.

You can replace half of this code with the safe and fast var response=await client.PostAsJsonAsync(uri,projectRecordsJson) or, if the class and DTO don't match, client.PostAsJsonAsync(url,new {projectRecordsJson.Uin,projectRecordsJson.ProjectId,...})

I found the culprit!
There's a specific formatting in projectRecordsJson.StopDate in which it uses this kind of format 2024-04-02T15:29:45.761Z, but what I'm sending is this 20240402.
But I used the proposed answer of Panagiotis Kanavos, which is better
var response=await client.PostAsJsonAsync(uri,projectRecordsJson)

